# the existence of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let$f$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that there exists a
> holomorphic function $g$  on $\mathbb{C}$ s.t $g'=f$.

My attempt is not too much, at least I have tried to think, but can't go further:
If $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$, then according to Liouville's theorem, $f$ is constant. Let $f=a\in\mathbb{C}$. We can choose $g(z)=az$ as a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$  s.t $g'=f$.
I'm stuck at the case that $f$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{C}$. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every entire function $f$ admits a power series expansion
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n, $$
which holds for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Thus
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n+1}z^{n+1} $$
will be the desired function.

Comment: Can I ask why $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Every power series is holomorphic (or complex-differentiable) in the domain of convergence. In this case, $f(z)$ converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and this implies that $g$ also converges on the whole complex plane (for example, by the Hadamard formula regarding the radius of convergence).

Comment: I don't understand, why $f(z)$ convergent for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ implies that $g$ also converges on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The Hadamard formula says that the radius $R$ of convergence of a power series is given by $1/R=\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}$. Since $\lim(n+1)^{1/n}=1$, $f$ and $g$ both have the same radius of convergence, which is $+\infty$.